# Heart rate monitoring & tracking with the Samsung Galaxy Gear (or similar) Smartwatch. Possible?

Tags: running, tracking, heart-rate-monitor

First, the faq states "gear and gadgets used during exercise" is on-topic. So I am going to ask about the Samsung Galaxy Gear Smartwatch (or similar watches) and I hope that is OK.

I would be interested in using a smartwatch as a full featured replacement for carrying my smartphone while running. I don't care about any phone-related functions. I don't even need to listen to music. I only care about tracking my workout in great detail. I want to record my route via GPS, my speed, my heart rate and even my cadence.

I use a Zephyr HxM that provides cadence, heart rate, and other data. (I also have a Zephyr BioHarness.)

Does anyone know if the capabilities of these new smartwatches that would make it possible to achieve my goals? If so, are there existing running apps that support this scenario?

Finally, since the Zephyr HxM provides r-r interval data, does any smartwatch app record this data?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question here? Currently this reads like a shopping recommendation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a product recommendation or review.

Comment: Is your question about the Samsung Galaxy Gear specifically? The way your question is currently worded is too open-ended and broad as it is.

Comment: @MattChan - well, the rules seem so ambiguous that I'm not sure how to reword it to be more specific to one product without it becoming a shopping question. Furthermore, I don't really care which brand/model watch I use. I just want to know if any current smartwatch could do all this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The galaxy gear actually links to your phone and can't do much without it (certainly not GPS), so it's not going to solve your problem with carrying your phone around. I believe the MIO alpha strapless monitor might be the sort of thing you are looking for ... there a review of it [here](http://www.runnersworld.com/electronics/mio-alpha-heart-rate-monitor?page=single). But that still won't give you GPS. [GPS watches](http://www.runnersworld.com/electronics/advanced-gps-running-watches) are rather pricey and ugly.

Comment: Thanks. That info helps. FYI, a strapless monitor won't do r-r interval heart beat monitoring. They are generally not nearly as accurate as strap-based monitors.